# Add column with xml data

Tags: list

I just want to add into my list, a column with xml data in sharepoint 2010.

I already have a list with XML document but I don't understand how it fetch data into xml, I have a column with "name", "date"....

I just want to add another data, but in my available column list (into library setting), I don't have my data.

Do you have an idea?

[my sharepoint list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CQ5rG.png)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new multiple lines of text column, set to plain text and unlimited length in document libraries. Then you should be able to put XML markup into the plain text field.

Comment: But I want dynamic data, who get from my xml document